# How to properly power this 1600nm LED diode?

Tags: voltage, led, current, raspberry-pi

I have powered LEDs in the past using my Raspberry Pi 4, but its 3V3 pin can't seem to power this LED.

Is the low current the Pi can provide the problem? I don't want to take chances since this LED is worth 30 bucks.

[image]

Comment: safiot - Hi, To comply with the site rule on [referencing](/help/referencing), please [edit] the question & add the PDF / video / webpage name and its link, for the source of that image. Also please remember it's your responsibility to follow that rule in future too. || As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as site rules here differ from typical forums. TY

Comment: Probably an IR LED? If you supply 3.3V to an IR LED, it'll be dead. You should provide 1.1 (min) to 1.4V (max) according to the datasheet you've provided. Note that human eyes can't see 1600nm either.

Comment: You are not supposed to drive high loads directly from GPIO pin. So it depends how much current you need. You only show a LED with some ratings but don't tell at what current you want to drive it.

Comment: While you risk possibly damaging the Pi, it should be able to light up that LED. You're checking with an IR card right? You will not see anything without one at 1600nm.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik There is no way that a silicon sensor can see 1600nm.

Comment: @user1850479 do you happen to know something about the safety precautions one would want to take working with such an ir-b emitter? 2 mW output doesn't seem dangerously much, but then again, my eye wouldn't blink, this being completely invisible...

Comment: @sinabala There are NIR medical imaging devices that use more than 2mW directly into the eye, so most likely that LED would be eye safe regardless of precautions. Plus 1600nm won't reach the retina due to water absorption . But I don't have the ANSI standard on me so don't quote me without doing the calculations yourself in case I'm forgetting something.